Acumatica is using mysql or sql how to identify in c# code
Acumatica is using mysql or sql how to identify in c# code. Or
In Acumatica how to get the provider name in C# code to identify the SQL or MySql.

If your instance is installed locally you should be able to find this info from the installer or configuration applications. If it is hosted then your provider can give you that info, or you can refer to my answer below to use a customisation to find the type and version from the database using a view, data access class and generic inquiry.

I used the Native/Skip SQL Script Attributes in a Customisation package to run the relevant "select version" script for the SQL version and present it using:

A View added to the SQL database.
A Data Access Class (DAC) for the View.
A Generic Inquiry (GI) using the DAC.

Customisation project.xml: https://pastebin.com/DCkRjxg1
Customisation: Database Script:
--[mysql: Skip]
--[mssql: Native]
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.SQLversion', 'V') IS NOT NULL DROP VIEW [SQLversion];
GO
--[mysql: Skip]
--[mssql: Native]
CREATE VIEW [SQLversion] AS (SELECT 'SQL Server' AS [Type],(SELECT @@VERSION) AS [Version])
GO

--[mysql: Native]
--[mssql: Skip]
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `SQLversion`;
CREATE VIEW `SQLversion` AS (SELECT 'MySQL' AS 'Type',(SELECT VERSION()) AS 'Version')
GO

Customisation: CODE > New DAC:
using System;
using PX.Data;

namespace SQLversion
{
  [Serializable]
  [PXCacheName("SQLversion")]
  public class SQLversion : IBqlTable
  {
    #region Type
    [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Type")]
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    public abstract class type : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<type> { }
    #endregion

    #region Version
    [PXDBString(2000, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Version")]
    public virtual string Version { get; set; }
    public abstract class version : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<version> { }
    #endregion
  }
}


Try reading the connection string from:
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings

Example here
SQL Server and My SQL have different connection string properties.
